# Perl Tk Label change background color associate with textvariable

Tags: perl, text, label, background-color, tk-toolkit

How to automatically change the label background color associate with textvariable?
i.e when textvariable is positive value , background change to green. When it is  minus value, it automatically change to red. Pls advise.

```
use strict;
use Tk;
my $mw = new MainWindow(-title => "TTTT",
 );
$mw->geometry( "400x300" );

my $LAST1 ;
my $bgclr = 'green';
my $label1 = $mw->Label ( -textvariable=>\$LAST1, -fg=>'White',
-font=> 'arial 20',
-bg => $bgclr,
);

$label1->place(-x=>10, -y => 65);

$mw->repeat(2000,\&tick);
MainLoop;


sub tick {

my $AA= '9.16';
my $sum = '235.72';
my $avge = (($sum + $AA) / 25);
my $RR = ((($AA - $avge) / $avge) *100);
$LAST1 = $RR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an Treads and Tread::Shared in a large scale programs in order to update the Main GUI while running an external subs.
But for your example this might be enough to start with.

Here is a sample code base on your provide code:

```
use strict;
use Tk;
our $time_tick = 1;
our $label1;
our $Pos_Color = 'green';
our $Neg_Color = 'red';
my $mw = new MainWindow(-title => "TTTT",
 );
$mw->geometry( "400x300" );

my $LAST1 ;
my $bgclr = $Pos_Color;
$label1 = $mw->Label ( -textvariable=>\$time_tick, -fg=>'White',
-font=> 'arial 20',
-bg => $bgclr,
);

$label1->place(-x=>10, -y => 65);

$mw->repeat(2000,\&tick);
MainLoop;


sub tick {
    $time_tick = $time_tick * -1;
    if ($time_tick > 0)
    {
        $label1->configure(-bg => $Pos_Color);
    }
    else
    {
        $label1->configure(-bg => $Neg_Color);  
    }
}
```